# Call a method in ASP.NET when the (browser/Session) is closed?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, browser

On a button click event i am trying to run a process , if that process has been terminated in the middle by closing the browser or due to internet connectivity issues I would want to update that this process has been Terminated/Failed in the database, how can I achieve that in asp.net? What are the best practice to handle such Events?

**SHORT EXPLANATION :**

1.User runs the process A by clicking the button for A,

2.User terminates browser and here i would like to update in database that "user terminated/failure of process?

3.How to call events on browser/Session forced termination?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can recommend you read about it in [this](https://eureka.ykyuen.info/2011/02/22/jquery-javascript-capture-the-browser-or-tab-closed-event/) article.

But nowadays we don't have any 100% method to detect this event.
Another way something with web sockets, when you leave page/browser you doing unsubscribe from your Hub. But I can't recommend this one, it just an options if you use web sockets/signalR on your backend.